# Android Firebase app crashes after updating ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-arrayadapter

Hello I am currently working on my very first android app and I have came across and issue where the Application crashes after I add an item into the database and attempt to display the additional item to the UI. 
I am using Firebase and a custom `ArrayAdapter` to display the database.
The issue only happens when I add a new item to the database and call updateUI().
The issue isn't in `updateUI()`, I know this because I call `updateUI()` in onCreate, and the database information is pulled successfully. Also if I use a traditional ArrayAdapter the process works. I was hoping to receive some help and understand why this problem is occurring.

Here is

> User.java

```
public void setUserInformation(String task){
    String removeFirstLast = task.substring(1, task.length()-1);
    String[] array = removeFirstLast.split(",");
    dueDate = array[0].substring(9, array[0].length());
    taskName = array[1].substring(11, array[1].length());
    courseName = array[2].substring(13, array[2].length());
}
```

> UserAdapter.java

```
public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>{

private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<User> data;
private final int layoutResourceId;
public UserAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<User> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.due_date);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    User user = data.get(position);

    holder.textView1.setText(user.getTaskName());
    holder.textView2.setText(user.getDueDate() + "-  " + user.getCourseName());


    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
}
```

updateUI() in list_activity.java
There was an issue where the only taskName was being pulled successfully from the database. Was receiving `NullPointerException` on courseName, dueDate.

```
private void updateUI(){
    final ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    //final ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

    //pull from database
    Query query = myRef.child("Users").child(user_id).child("TO DO");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //    courseName = ds.child("Course Name").getValue().toString();
                //    taskName = ds.child("Task Name").getValue().toString();
                //    dueDate = ds.child("Due Date").getValue().toString();
                String task = ds.getValue().toString();
                //taskList.add(taskName);
                user = new User();
                userList.add(user);
                user.setUserInformation(task);
                //   user.setCourseName(courseName);
                //    user.setDueDate(dueDate);
                //   user.setTaskName(taskName);



                //    Log.i("AlertDialog","Due Date Entered "+ dueDate);
                //    Log.i("AlertDialog","Course Name Entered "+ courseName);
                //    Log.i("AlertDialog","Task Name Entered "+ taskName);
                Log.i("AlertDialog","Task Entered "+ task);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    if (mAdapter == null) {
     //    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
      //   R.layout.list_item,
      //   R.id.task_title,
     //    taskList);
      //   mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter = new UserAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, userList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(userList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

To summarize even with the error, data is still added to the database, `updateUI()` successfully pulls database information, the application closes after calling `updateUI()` again once the user has uploaded new info to the database. The issue does not occur when a traditional `ArrayAdapter` is used.

I receive an array out of bounds error, even though I know this is not the issue.

```
11-21 23:38:31.883 9431-9431/com.example.android.procastinator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.android.procastinator, PID: 9431
                                                                             java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                                                                                 at com.example.android.procastinator.User.setUserInformation(User.java:61)
                                                                                 at com.example.android.procastinator.list_Activity$2.onDataChange(list_Activity.java:158)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is an example of what String task is equal to

```
{Due Date=11/25/17, Task Name=HW 6, Course Name=CSC 4360}
```

Comment: I am no longer using setUserInformation and using getters/setters to save info from database. Receiving Attempt to invoke method on null object .toString

Comment: Can you try printing the task value , it is possible that the task doesn't have comma separated values.

Comment: So I made a discovery that the application crashes upon attempting to retrieve the lastest item in the database. Is FireBase to slow? It is able to retrieve it upon re opening the app.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but I recommend to use [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library with the built-in [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md). You save a lot of headache.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong but is it a race condition? Since the issue occurs right after I add a new item to the database. The app crashes when it attempts to pull the values of the new item. But if I reload the app everything (including the newest item is loaded successfully). Will delay calling updateUI() fix the problem? Maybe add a splashscreen?

Comment: The task being pulled in is separated by comma values, I checked it by converting it to a string and viewing it. Also I don't think the app would of loaded/ or the output would of been chopped up, but that wasn't the case. I am no longer using setUserInformation(), and storing the values using getters/setters from User. @aurilio

Answer (score 0):

I think a better idea would be to create a table for you data rather than getting a string and parsing it. And just retrieve the value as object rather than string. This will probably save you from ArraysOutOfBoundException.

```
 Users users = ds.getValue(Users.class);
```

The Users table in firebasedatabase

```
{
  "users": {
       "asdfas12321": {
              "Due Data": "11/25/17",
              "Task Name": "Hw 6",
              "Course Name": "CSC 4360",
              },
       "asdfa112312": { ... },
       "1241dwqreq": { ... }
     }
}
```